# Replacing wrong codificaton letters with SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, replace

I have a database with data from internet, but some pages have wrong codification and letters like `ã` becomes `Ã£` and `ç`becomes `Ã§`.

What are the possibilities to fix this? I'm using PostgreSQL.

I can use replace, but I need to do a replace for each case? I was thinking about translate, but I see that it transforms only one char into other. Is possible translate two chars into one? Something like: `TRANSLATE(text,'Ã£|Ã§','ã|ç')`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This particular problem looks like you have UTF-8 encoding being interpreted as a single-byte character set ("ç" becoming "Ã§" suggests iso-8859-1).

You can fix these up individually with a long chain of `replace(...)` calls. Or you can use postgresql's own character-conversion facilities:

```
select convert_from(convert_to('Â£20 - garÃ§on', 'iso-8859-1'), 'utf-8')
```

In order, this:

- Converts the string back to binary using the iso-8859-1 codec (which will just change unicode codepoints back to bytes, assuming all the codepoints are under 256)
- Reinterprets that binary output as UTF-8, so sequences such as {0xc2, 0xa3} are translated to '£'

Comment: I think this is the best way, but there are invalid chars that cannot be converted like `0xe7e36f` and `0xefbfbd`. How I can identify the string that haves these invalid chars and replace they with some symbol like `?`.?

Comment: unfortunately, postgresql's converter is strict and doesn't allow that... you could write a pl/perl function to use Perl's looser transcoding routines instead?

Comment: `\xe7e36f` looks like "ção" in iso-8859-1 ... suggests that you have a mix of things that have been interpreted wrongly and things that have been interpreted correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You can fix some of the characters by replacing them, but not all. By decoding the data using the wrong encoding you have already removed some information, and that is impossible to get back.

You should find out what the correct encoding is for those pages, and use that when decoding the data.

Some pages have the encoding in the response header, e.g.

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf8
```

Some pages have the encoding in the HTML head, e.g.

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

If the information is not in the header you would first have to decode the page (or at least a part of it) using the ASCII encoding (which is not a problem as the meta tag contains no special characters), find out the encoding, then decode the page using the correct encoding.

Comment: +1. Altough this is not an answer to the question asked, this is something that needs to be done in the long run.

Comment: @jmz Yes, I know that is a thing to do too and the library I'm using in Java do this for most pages, but I'm not sure that it works for all cases without exceptions. Another think is that some pages can have their original content with the errors by the page's developer mistake.

Answer (score 1):

PostgreSQL has a string replacement function:

`replace(string text, from text, to text)`: Replace all occurrences in `string` of substring `from` with substring `to`

Example:

`replace ('abcdefabcdef', 'cd', 'XX') ==> abXXefabXXef`